# Class Template deduction Guide- Error on MVS

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I was trying to compile the code below (containing a Deduction Guide), but I got errors on MVS (2017) (it works fine with mingw).

So how could i resolve this in MVS / or is it not supported ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Element {

public:
    Element() {};
    Element(T const&) {};
};

//don't wrap C-strings in Elements...
Element(char const*)-> Element<std::string>;

int main()
{
    Element el{ "Hello!" };
    std::cout << typeid(el).name();
}
```

Error on Visual Studio :

> error C2955: 'Element': use of class template requires template
> argument list
>
> note: see declaration of 'Element'
>
> error C2062: type 'const char' unexpected
>
> note: see declaration of 'Element'

Comment: you need add `/std:c++17` or `/std:c++latest` compiler option. or use `Element<char*> el{ "Hello!" };` - [*Enable supported C++ language features from the specified version of the C++ language standard.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=vs-2017)

Comment: @RbMm : none of them did work. Even if I changed the `Element<char*> el{ "Hello!" };`

Comment: *`Even if I changed the Element<char*> el{ "Hello!" };`* and the error in this case what ? (for me this is compile with no errors) ? also what is `_MSVC_LANG` value ?

Comment: the error is `error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'Element<char *>'` and how to get the  _MSVC_LANG ?

Comment: `#define _A(x) #x
#define A(x) _A(x)
#pragma message ("_MSVC_LANG=" A(_MSVC_LANG))` for example

Comment: I think sth like 201402L So I guess it has to be sth like 2017XXL
and current VS version  is 15.8.5

Comment: with `201402L` - `Element<char*> el{ "Hello!" }` must be ok. with `/std:c++17`` must be `_MSVC_LANG=2017**L` and no errors in `Element el{ "Hello!" };`

Comment: So I guess I have to upgrade my vs to 15.9.x ... Thank you for the support.